# Android converting color string to resource int

Tags: android, android-resources, android-color

I am trying to set color from a json color array to my custom menu background.

`addMenuItem(int bgColor);`

json color array =>

```
[
  [
    "B71C1C",
    "C62828"],[
    "B71C1C",
    "C62828"]
]
```

Color String is getting correctly from json

`String colorString = "#" + mColors.getJSONArray(i%2).getString(i%2);` gives #B71C1C;

While convert it to integer `int parseColor = Color.parseColor(colorString);`
and passing to above menu background;

`ie;addMenuItem(parseColor);`

I'm getting

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffb71c1c

I think addMenuItem will accept int only from resource. How can I set color from my JSON color file.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are throwing in a number and the Android framework tries to find a resource for that (R.color) which doesn't exist. You should convert that number to a `Color` object, using `Color.argb(int,int,int,int)` for example